# Give a user the ability to change a function in my R package

Tags: r, package, rcpp

I am currently creating an R package and have the following issue. The package has one R routine, say aR, and two Rcpp routines, say bC and cC. Both aR and bC call cC. I would like the user to be able to create their own version of cC.

One solution would of course be to simply "open" the code of the three routines so a user can replace cC and just reinstall the package, but the actual package contains almost 20 routines and I don't want to make most of these visible to the user.

I tried the following already:

```
environment(newcC) <- asNamespace('packagename')
assignInNamespace("cC", newcC, ns = "packagename")
```

and that works for aR, it now runs cC instead of newcC. But it does not work with bC, it keeps using the original routine cC.

Comment: You could define `aR` so that one of its arguments is the function to use for `cC`, and the default value of that argument is the `cC` defined within the package

Comment: For example, like this: `fun_plus_one <- function(x, fun = sum) { fun(x) + 1 }; fun_plus_one(1:3, fun = min)`. It would return `7` if no `fun` is provided when the function is called, but when called with `fun = min` it returns `2`.

Comment: I think you are up against 'sealed namespaces' as created by a package. Rcpp does not change this, its caller functions are typically R too (which call the C++ functions).

Comment: I figured it was something like that. When I saw that assignInNamespace worked for R code I was hoping it would work for Rcpp code as well, but apparently not.

Comment: Rcpp code _is_ R code.  The package simply hides its use of helpers giving you (lightweight) *R functions* that call `.Call()` on to the entry points your actual C++ code provides.  Makes the thinking simpler:  it's still all R code _at the interface_, and abides by the same rules.  Even if the work is done in C++.

Answer (score 0):

IceCreamToucan's suggestion to simply make cC an argument works just fine, so thanks!

Wolfgang